# How to make fixed position element has width automatically based on image width and in a certain in its maximum if the image is too large?

Tags: html, css

I want to create an element with properties
`position:fixed; width:auto; max-width:90%` (more in my example below) and it will contain an image element.

The image itself has this properties `display:block; width:auto; max-width:100%; max-height:100%`

My expectation was, the image would extends the parent width automatically, it reached maximum width of parent if the image is larger than maximum width of parent, and the image would remain in its ratio.

The result is, smaller than my expectation (that's what she said). The image only extends the parent in amount of small width although the image is actually bigger than that.

```css
.item{
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
width:auto;
max-width:90%;
max-height:90%;
overflow:auto;
background:#060008;
padding:5px
}

.item img{
display:block;
width:auto;
max-width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Sports_shoes.jpg'/>
</div>
```

How do i make the image would extends the parent width in same size and it limits in maximum width of parent if the image is larger than maximum width of parent?
In example above, my expectation was the image would extends the parent width until 90% width of `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

Your `.item` class has `max-width`, which is saying "The biggest this element can be is 90% of its parent."

But, you've got nothing that actually *makes* the element that big! Adding `width: 100%` to `.item` will attempt to make `.item` full-width, but it will be stopped at `90%` by your `max-width`.

At this point you'll probably want to add a `max-height: 90%` along with your `max-width`, to support more screen aspect ratios, and add CSS to truly constrain the image within its `.item` container.

```css
.item{
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
width:100%;
max-width:90%;
background:#060008;
padding:5px
}

.item img{
display:block;
width:auto;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Sports_shoes.jpg'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if my grammar is awful sir. I want the .item follows whatever image width but 90% width of viewport in maximum. If i have the image has the width only 500pixels maybe in my 1080p screen or less than 90% width of my viewport, the .item would be oversized.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use top/left with `50%`. This will constrain the image to half the size. Consider a different way to center:

```css
.item {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #060008;
  padding: 5px
}

.item img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
  <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Sports_shoes.jpg' />
</div>
```